# Java converting char to string won't work

Tags: java, string, char

Why does this return false? How can I get it to return true?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        char character = 'X';
        String x = Character.toString(character);
        System.out.println(x == "X"); // returns false
    }
}
```

Comment: The most duplicate SO question ever. I wonder how on earth Java tutorials out there are written that this question doesn't cease to reappear on a way too regular basis.

Comment: I'm crying.. again :__(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Character.toString(character)` returns a new `String` . Hence `x =="X"` is `false`. `==` compares references , not contents. To compare `String` , use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
System.out.println(x.equals("X"));
```

`Character.toString(character);` calls `String.valueOf(character)`, whose code is :

```
public static String valueOf(char c) {
  char data[] = {c};
  return new String(0, 1, data); // new String object created here
}
```

Hence your comparison of object reference using `==` fails .

Comment: Duhhh! I did learn about equals(), but I totally forget about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [String.equals(otherString)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) function to compare `strings`, not the `==` operator.

The reason is that `==` just compares object references,where as `.equals()` checks `equality`.

```
 System.out.println(x.equals("X"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare strings in Java with `==` in general. Use `x.equals("X")`. Otherwise you're using *reference equality* and are in fact testing that both `x` and `"X"` are the same reference (which is unlikely to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

== operator in Java checks whether the two references are pointing to the same object or now. Which is false in your case.
For String comparison, use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`